# NBO natural bond orbital

Tags: bond

Is it always reliable the bonding description of a molecular system you obtain using the NBO method? In which cases do you consider that it is necessary to have special care when analyzing the NBO results?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry! Take the [tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with this site. Right now, your question is very broad. In general, localization-based methods have a tough time with delocalized systems. It would be better if you gave more concrete examples of systems you're trying to study.